# How to send Parameters to the servlet using Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to send parameters using jquery ajax. I am able to call servlet using jquery ajax but unable to send any parameters.. My code is---

```
function callServlet(){
            var abc='hello';                
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../d3data",                
                dataType: "json",
                data: {name : abc},
                success:function(data){
                    if(data){
                        alert("worked");
                    }
                },
                error:function(){
                    alert('not worked.');
                } 

            })       
        };
```

My servlet's name is d3data.. In servlet I read this value using

```
String name=request.getParameter("name");
```

Please any one help me.....

Comment: Do you mean to use `GET` instead of `POST`?

Comment: Your URL is pointing to a d3data folder on the client's machine.
Use `http://server_ip_or_domain_name/whatever/d3data/`

Comment: no, that URL is relative to wherever the page was downloaded from.

Answer (score 1):

```
function callServlet(){
            var abc='hello';                
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "../d3data",                
                dataType: "json",
                data: {"name" : abc},
                success:function(data){
                    if(data){
                        alert("worked");
                    }
                },
                error:function(){
                    alert('not worked.');
                } 

            })       
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
```

or request post parameters in controller

Answer (score 0):

To *retrieve* data from a servlet, you should be using the `GET` method.  Furthermore, `GET` requests should generally be "idempotent", such that repeating the same request over and over does not generate different data.

The `POST` method is intended for sending *bulk* data to a servlet, and in particular when the sending of that data is supposed to have side effects *on the server*, such that the request is not idempotent.